# Filter data from BigQuery by using "last day of previous week"

Tags: date, filter, google-bigquery, between, int64

For my BigQuery request I want to define to dates in the Between function as string. But I get the following error message `'Cannot read field 'date' of type INT64 as STRING'`. 
My calculation of `LastDayofPreviusWeek` works in `SELECT` clause and gives correct results as well, but I can't use in `WHERE` clause? Any ideas?

```sql
SELECT
FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date), WEEK(MONDAY)),INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as LastDayofPreviousWeek,
sum(totals.bounces) as Bounces
from `xxx.ga_sessions_*` t
WHERE
_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 71 DAY))
AND
FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date), WEEK(MONDAY)),INTERVAL 1 DAY))
group by 1
```

Sample input data:

```
date,    Bounces
20201118, 18695
20201119, 18694
20201120, 18693
```

Comment: can you provide some sample data?  But my guess is you will need to cast date as a string.

Comment: Field date is defined as String in YYYYMMDD like '20201120'

Comment: date, Bounces
20201118, 18695
20201119, 18694
20201120, 18693

Answer (score 0):

The below allows your `LastDayofPreviousWeek` to execute.
You need to cast the date as a string.
However there are still issues with your sql statement specifically in your `WHERE` clause that you will need to address and actually set an operator and a value to evaluate.

```
with temp as (
SELECT 20201118 date, 18695 Bounces UNION ALL
SELECT 20201119, 18694 UNION ALL
SELECT 20201120, 18693
)

SELECT
FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', cast(date as string)), WEEK(MONDAY)),INTERVAL 1 DAY)) as LastDayofPreviousWeek,
sum(t.bounces) as Bounces
from temp t
```